# How to do event handling using javascript in html form page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have made an html page giving extension of php and its name is 'welcome.php'.In that page I am having a button named as "baggage.php" and on clicking it another page opens. I have kept 'To' and 'From' dropdown in that page with a 'Go' button . Now I want to give conditions that if the some option from dropdown is selected then it should redirect on 'webform1.php' page else if it should go on 'webform2.php' page else on 'webform3.php' page .

I have tried using javscript onclick() event but its not working for me.

```html
<h2>Track your baggage</h2>
   <br>
   <form>From
   <select>
   <option value="surat">Surat</option>
   <option value="ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
   <option value="gandhinagar">Gandhinagar</option>
   <option value="delhi">Delhi</option></select>   &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      To
   <select>
   <option value="surat">Surat</option>
   <option value="ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
   <option value="gandhinagar">Gandhinagar</option>
   <option value="delhi">Delhi</option></select><br><br>
   <input type="button" value="Go" name="Go">
```

### Track your baggage

```
        <br>
        <form>From
        <select>`enter code here`
        <option value="surat">Surat</option>
        <option value="ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
        <option value="gandhinagar">Gandhinagar</option>
        <option value="delhi">Delhi</option></select>           &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                    To
        <select>
        <option value="surat">Surat</option>
        <option value="ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
        <option value="gandhinagar">Gandhinagar</option>
        <option value="delhi">Delhi</option></select><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Go" name="Go"/>
```

I expect output that the if options are selected then it should redirect to other page which gives me the relevant output

Comment: you should assign names to each `select` menu

Comment: I have already assigned it....

Comment: not that is visible in the question you have not

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear but I think something like the following might help ~ though you'll need to edit it

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('select').addEventListener( 'change', function(e){
        let destination;

        switch( this.value ){
            case 'surat': 
            case 'ahmedabad':
                destination='webform1.php';
            break;

            case 'gandhinagar':
                destination='webform2.php';
            break;

            default:
                destination='webform3.php';
            break;
        }

        location.href=destination;

    }, false );
</script>
```

Or, if the same event listener is to work with both select menus you can use a different approach

```
<form>
    From
    <select name='from'>
        <option value="surat">Surat
        <option value="ahmedabad">Ahmedabad
        <option value="gandhinagar">Gandhinagar
        <option value="delhi">Delhi
    </select>

    To
    <select name='to'>
        <option value="surat">Surat
        <option value="ahmedabad">Ahmedabad
        <option value="gandhinagar">Gandhinagar
        <option value="delhi">Delhi
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <input type="button" value="Go" name="Go" />
</form>
<script>

    Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('select') ).forEach( select =>{
        select.addEventListener( 'change', function(e){
            let destination;

            switch( this.value ){
                case 'surat': 
                case 'ahmedabad':
                    destination='webform1.php';
                break;

                case 'gandhinagar':
                    destination='webform2.php';
                break;

                default:
                    destination='webform3.php';
                break;
            }

            location.href=destination;

        }, false );
    });
</script>
```